# Pandas 0.25.0 cannot create cursor for read_sql - throwing error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I keep getting an error with Pandas' 0.25.0 read_sql(). The code below is supposed to establish a couple connections, check if tables need to be created, and then begin extracting the result set from Oracle.

Stack Trace

```
RESTART: C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\xxxx\main.py 
Creating connections
Attempting to connect
Connection to box_db Successful
Attempting to connect
Connection to JDE Successful
Box table already existed
BoxStaging table already existed
LotStartSiteMap table already existed
Extracting from JDE
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\xxxx\main.py", line 42, in <module>
   main()
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\xxxx\main.py", line 26, in main
   df = data.box_data_extract(queries.BOX_QUERY, jde_conn)
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\xxxx\data.py", line 46, in box_data_extract
   pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
   chunksize=chunksize,
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1645, in read_query
   cursor = self.execute(*args)
 File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1590, in execute
   cur = self.con.cursor()
AttributeError: module 'connection' has no attribute 'cursor'
```

main.py

```
import connection
import credential
import data
import emailer
import queries
import tables

def main():

    # Create connection to box_db file and JDE
    #
    print("Creating connections")
    sqlite_conn = connection.box_db_connect(tables.DB_PATH)
    jde_conn = connection.mrap0680_connect(credential.USERNAME, credential.MRAP0680_PASSWORD)

    # If new path has been chosen create sqlite db and tables accordingly
    #
    tables.create_box_table(sqlite_conn)
    tables.create_box_staging_table(sqlite_conn)
    tables.create_lot_startsite_map_table(sqlite_conn)

    # Extract & insert JDE Box Query results into BoxStaging table
    #
    print("Extracting from JDE")
    df = data.box_data_extract(queries.BOX_QUERY, jde_conn) #############LINE CAUSING ERROR
    print("Storing in box_db")
    data.box_data_insert(df, sqlite_conn)
    print("BoxStaging updated")
```

data.py

```
# Extract the box data from JDE
#
def box_data_extract(query, connnection):
    try:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
        print("JDE Box Data extracted")
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

connection.py

```
def xxxx_connect(username, password):
    # Connect to JDE database
    try:
        print("Attempting to connect")
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=DSN_TNS)
        print("Connection to JDE Successful")
        return conn

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

I am able to extract the data if running manually.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Update: I changed the name of connection.py to connections.py to ensure there was no module name conflict. I also added a cursor to connections.py. Now I am receiving a different error: ```TypeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object is not callable```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error! The issue was in data.py. In the parameter list of data_box_extract, connection is spelled as "connnection". Inside the function, "connection" was being used so a cursor couldn't be instantiated. Not sure why it didn't throw an error about "connection" not being instantiated. Oh well, I'm writing the program in IDLE, maybe it's time to switch to an IDE that will catch those mistakes...
Thanks to all who viewed!